# printing the result of multiplication of return of function ( int ) and a float number constant

Tags: c

i have a problem where the function somme_diagonale return the right result when called in main, but as soon as i multiply it to ( 2 / 9 ) and print the result it appears to be 0.

function :

````
{
    int i, s = 0 ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        s = s + mat [ i ] [ i ] ;
    }
    return s ;
}```

call : 


``` printf("resultat est : %f", ( float ) ( 2 / 9 ) * somme_diagonale ( F ) );```



i have tested that somme_diagonale ( F ) returns 165 ( int ).

can someone help me ?
````

Comment: `( float ) ( 2 / 9 )` The cast happens _after_ the integer division. Need to cast before that or just do `2.0f / 9.0f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hi,` in order to have a `float` value, either the 2 or the 9 must be cast. This, though, must happen *before* the division is performed. `(2/9)` produces a result of type `int`, which only *then* is cast to `float`.
What you should do is replace that piece of code with of these options (sorry in advance, I'm not a fan of spaces):

- (float)2 / 9 * somme_diagonale(F)
- 2 / (float)9 * somme_diagonale(F)
- (float)2 / (float)9 * somme_diagonale(F)